# ASUS VivoBook K403FA laptop will not turn on unless battery is disconnected then reconnected

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I have started learning hardware and fixing laptops in my spare time. I am at a loss with this one. Was hoping to get some insight as to what is wrong.

The laptop is an ASUS VivoBook K403FA. Originally the keyboard was broken (no keys worked at all) however, this turned out just to be a loose connection. However, I've now noticed that the laptop will not turn on unless I disconnect the battery and then reconnect the battery.

Whether or not the laptop is turning on, there is a charging indicator and when I do manage to get into Windows, Windows is showing that the laptop is charging. But when I then shut Windows down, I can only power up the laptop if I quickly open it up, disconnect the battery and reconnect it. I haven't managed to find much on google relating to this issue.

Also to  note, if the battery is removed and im only using mains, same issue. I have flashed the bios to no avail.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an issue with the BIOS CR2032 battery, or more likely, the main one. What does the battery report say? - https://www.windowscentral.com/how-check-your-laptops-battery-health-windows-10

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that this issue also exists without the battery (on mains) mean the battery cannot be at fault? I am hoping it's something like that though and not a problem with the motherboard.

Comment: Ah, missed your very last comment. I don't know how easy it is to open up your laptop (and if you know what an antistatic wristband is), but it might be worth popping in a new CR2032, just to rule that out (the battery report does not include this CR2032). They're pretty cheap and universally available. Is your laptop still under warranty?

Comment: I have read it could be the CMOS battery so for the price as you said, its worth a shot. I do know what an antistatic wristband is etc, I'm not too new to this but compared to others I know nothing! With that said, I have looked and cannot find the battery on my board. I have looked up where it could be for this particular laptop and had no luck. I have also taken the motherboard out and it's not on the other side either. I'll look again. Thanks!

Comment: It might be 'packaged': https://en.accessoires-asus.com/cmos-asus-battery-for-vivobook-64056-58596.htm - inside this is a regular CR2032, that's the one you want to replace.

Comment: Antistatic wristband / strap / bracelet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antistatic_device - even tiny bits of static electricity can cause damage in PCs, this thing keeps your charge to zero if you wear it and hook it up to a grounded object, while you perform surgery on the laptop (a nearby radiator usually works).

Comment: I have not been able to locate the battery. I am guessing that it does not have one and from my research, it is common for laptops to not have a cmos battery. Some more information: laptop is able to restart many times and power up fine by pressing 'restart' in windows. It will just not start again if shut down. As for the power button, it is fine when pressed to turn off the laptop, but will NOT turn it back on unless the battery is disconnected and reconnected. I can only guess that for whatever reason, the power button doesn't work if there is static charge?

Comment: All my laptops have a CMOS battery, could be related to specific ranges I suppose (perhaps a capacitor + relying on the large battery is cheaper). I vaguely recall there's a BIOS setting about power state upon losing power. Although it's not exactly the same, you might benefit from doing a CMOS reset. Depends on the brand (and sometimes type) what the procedure is, but it'll usually be holding the power button for a while.

Comment: I'll keep looking into it, I've updated the bios and have also held the power button down for a good amount of time (like a full minute) and nothing is working. Could it be that somehow the power button isn't giving enough power? I don't know how I'd test this as I can't see any settings in the BIOS for a secondary power button. Which by the way is located on the keyboard itself and isn't separate to the keyboard.

Comment: Power button's just an on/off switch, if you've passed its pressure threshold that's enough. These things aren't physical buttons anymore either, they tell the main board to power up. I haven't delved deeply, but I recall someone mentioning they held it for two minutes. I also vaguely recall someone mentioning some kind of tampering override that locks up the device, so I would read up on this first for your specific model!

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. The problem seems to have gone away on its own? The only things that happened were: 1.  I left it running for a while and 2. Installed Windows 11. But I don't see how installing windows 11 would've helped, I literally stripped it of all of its components (including the SSD) and only had what was needed to power up into the BIOS and still the issue was there. I'll need to do further testing before selling it on as a working unit though. I need to know why it suddenly worked

Answer (score 0):

Problem somehow went away on its own.

Windows 11 was installed.
Machine was left on doing nothing for a couple hours.

I don't understand what has fixed it, as the laptop was stripped of everything apart from what was needed to boot into bios, including the SSD. So surely Windows 11 didn't fix the issue. As for leaving it running, I had previously used the laptop for a while and the issue was still there... Somehow leaving it running doing minimum tasks might've worked?

In either case I am quite bothered that there is no clear answer as to what worked - I plan to sell this on as a working machine so will look into an answer for this.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that the battery needed a minimum charge to exist. Meaning when you disassembled the machine, the battery drained to 0% and then when you hooked it up again, it worked but only so far. And then when you stopped looking at it (a magical way to fix things) the battery had enough time to get at least a basic charge in place. Like 5% to 10%?

Comment: Problem starting again, seems leaving it on for a while solves it temporarily. But this problem doesn't exist on mains, I thought it did - but it didn't. It was just taking longer to start when on mains. I strong think this is a battery issue now and have ordered a new OEM battery. So I'll know for sure next week.

Comment: New battery did not work however, the fault is non existent after spending a good few minutes inserting the battery connector carefully. Both batteries (new and old) work perfectly although it does seem overly hard to get the connection right. I'm either dumb or the connector on the motherboard is finicky. The fact it worked perfectly before was nothing to do with 'leaving it alone' but rather I had connected it exactly right.